# When using Dash tables with selectable rows, is there a way to select them all?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When using dash tables like

```
dash_table.DataTable(
            id='datasource-interactivity',
            columns= [
                #{"name": i, "id": i} for i in data_all.columns 
                {"name": i, "id": i, "selectable": True} for i in data_all.columns
                ],
            data=data_all.to_dict('records'), 
            filter_action="native",
            sort_action="native",
            sort_mode="multi",
            column_selectable="single",
            row_selectable="multi",   #<-----
            selected_columns=[],
            selected_rows=[],   #<------THIS
            page_action="native",
            page_current= 0,
            page_size= 100,
            )
```

Is there a way to:

1. Initialize them all to selected?
2. Select and un-select them all?

Answer (score 0):

`selected_rows` is just a list of row indexes.

Let's say we have a method to produce all row indexes of the given data frame:

```
def list_all_row_indexes(data_frame: pd.DataFrame) -> list[int]:
    return list(range(len(data_frame.index)))
```

Than the `selected_rows` attribute is initialized with it's result:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    ...
    selected_rows=list_all_row_indexes(data_all),  #<------THIS
    ...
```

A simple button with a callback to deselect all rows:

```
deselect_all_button = html.Button('Deselect all', id='deselect_all_button')


@app.callback(
    Output('datasource-interactivity', 'selected_rows', allow_duplicate=True),
    Input('deselect_all_button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def deselect_all_button_click(_) -> list:
    return []
```

The similar one to select all:

```
select_all_button = html.Button('Select all', id='select_all_button')


@app.callback(
    Output('datasource-interactivity', 'selected_rows', allow_duplicate=True),
    Input('select_all_button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def select_all_button_click(_) -> list:
    return list_all_row_indexes(data_all)
```

Should be noted, that these methods work with all the table rows, disregarding filters and pages.